# isn't going anywhere vs. [pronoun]'s not going anywhere

Tags: colloquial-language, contractions

[he's not going anywhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%27s%20not%20going%20anywhere%22&biw=1855&bih=982&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBsxokXIEpYMyZ4fN7df0-yB1Aj9rQ%3A1649256274636&ei=UqdNYq7CJtnXhwOv8qHICA&ved=0ahUKEwius5Kz1v_2AhXZ62EKHS95CIkQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22he%27s%20not%20going%20anywhere%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEAM6BQgAEIAEOgQIIRAKUKodWPsuYKgwaABwAHgAgAE8iAHRCJIBAjI3mAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz-books) has 49,600 results.

[he isn't going anywhere](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22he%20isn%27t%20going%20anywhere%22&biw=1855&bih=982&tbm=bks&sxsrf=APq-WBtY9r_UiF2xq-4LNe1FyDJVkeXbaA%3A1649256330593&ei=iqdNYs3yI8T1-Qbv4b_IAQ&ved=0ahUKEwjN3-nN1v_2AhXEet4KHe_wDxkQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22he%20isn%27t%20going%20anywhere%22&gs_lcp=Cg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzEANQlt8BWPvnAWCz6QFoAnAAeACAATOIAecDkgECMTKYAQCgAQHAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz-books) has 5,650 results.

(I performed a similar search in a private library, and the difference was more or less the same.)

Is the second contraction less common in this kind of sentence? If so, what could be the reason?

Comment: Probably so that the speaker can emphasize "not". How do the contracted forms compare to "he is not going anywhere"?

Comment: Those searches do not reflect how people actually speak which is impossible to gauge.

Answer (score 0):

I had noticed the much higher frequency of the first structure a long time ago, and your search confirmed my guess, because I don't remember many (or in fact any) instances of hearing "isn't" and "aren't" in American movies. It's (almost) always like this:

He's not there. / They're not here.
Is he a student? No, he's not.
Are they going somewhere? No, they're not.

My guess is that it's because "isn't" and "aren't" take a little more energy to pronounce than "'s not" and "'re not". The latter two are easier to prnounce. You can try it for yourself and make a comparison.

Comment: That comment about American movies makes little sense. "isn't" and "aren't" are everywhere in American movies just like in everyday language.